# Lógica do if com tipo bool e tipo object

Tags: javascript, typescript, lógica

Olá, estou quebrando a cabeça nessa lógica e não estou conseguindo resolver;

Tenho esse código:

```js
for(let i = 0; i < mensagemDeErroDoInput.length; i++) 
{
    if(statusInput[mensagemDeErroDoInput[i].nome] === true)
    {
        return mensagemDeErroDoInput[i].mensagem;
    }
}
```

Um IF dentro de um FOR, bem simples!

Imagina assim:
   1- Tenho dois tipos de parâmetros, um parametro me retorna bool e o outro me retorna um object;

***parâmetro de retorno bool, me retorna isso: true;***

***parâmetro de retorno object, me retorna isso: {valid: false};***

Esses parâmetros são minhas referências de mensagens de erro, ou seja, se meu parâmetro de retorno bool for igual a true, então eu retorno uma mensagem de erro.

E se meu parâmetro de retorno object for diferente de null, então eu retorno uma mensagem de erro.

Porém, todos os meus parâmetros de retorno bool, automaticamente já são diferente de null. Assim não estou conseguindo fazer essa validação dentro do meu for.

Alguém por favor poderia me ajudar??

Agradeço desde já...

Comment: O que vc chama de "parâmetro bool" e "parâmetro object"? Achei meio confusas essas nomenclaturas, e isso dificulta um pouco o entendimento da questão.

Comment: Ah sim, vou editar minha pergunta, assim melhorando a leitura. Agradeço a dica

Comment: Esses "*parâmetros de retorno*" são os `mensagemDeErroDoInput[i].nome`? Se não forem, qual(is) são as respecticas variáveis/expressões que os armazenam?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo! Então. uma é boolean, e a outra eu não tenho certeza, pois estou utilizando typescript + angular e não consigo achar o tipo da variável. Porém o retorno desse 'object' é exatamente como mostrei acima na pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testa o tipo e valor desejado conforme:

```
for(let i = 0; i < mensagemDeErroDoInput.length; i++) 
{
    var statusInputCorrente = statusInput[mensagemDeErroDoInput[i].nome];
    if((typeof statusInputCorrente === "object" && statusInputCorrente != null) || (typeof statusInputCorrente === "boolean" && statusInputCorrente === true))
    {
        return mensagemDeErroDoInput[i].mensagem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfeito kra, funcionou 100%! Muito obrigado

Comment: Agradecido por poder lhe ajudar @GuilhermeNunes.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o que você quer seria isso:

```
for (let i = 0; i < mensagemDeErroDoInput.length; i++) {
    var erro = mensagemDeErroDoInput[i];
    var status = statusInput[erro.nome];
    if (typeof status === "boolean" ? status === true : status !== null) {
        return erro.mensagem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Não é bem isso! acabei de editar a pergunta informando o tipo de retorno que recebo desses parâmetros..
Agradeço

Answer (score 1):

Um objeto vai ser sempre true, então se você quer ver se ele existe usa o if(typeof nomedoobjeto == "undefined"){codigo}  E com questão de boleano acho melhor você dar uma olhada nesse aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36709116/logical-not-on-boolean-object-always-return-false-in-javascript

A primeira e a segunda resposta pode resolver seu problema.

Comment: Eu tinha lindo essa pagina antes de escrever essa pergunta e não é o que eu estou precisando. :/ ta complicado essa kkk. Mas agradeço